# How do you show that a language is in the class P, or Unknown?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, complexity-theory, turing-machines, np

I have two languages:

```
L1 = { <G> | G is a graph that contained a n - 5 clique }
L2 = { <G> | G is a graph that contained an Euler path }
```

I need to figure out if these languages are in class P or unknown.

For L1 I think is in class P because the size of the group is constant we have only n^5 groups like that that have n - 5 cliques. so the time complexity O-Notation is O(n^5).

For L2 I think is unknown, I don't know why.

I don't know how to prove these I have an idea for L1 to make an algorithm that runs over the graph for each group of 5 vertexes and checks if they are cliques-5 if yes accept otherwise reject.

for L2 I don't have any idiea

any help will be appreciated, Thanks a lot!

Comment: Euler path: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eulerian_path#Hierholzer's_algorithm

Comment: Yes, i searched for that but I don't know how to formally prove if it is in P or unknown with that algorithm

Comment: @Martian_mars For the second, Euler's theorem says that it is sufficient to verify all vertices have even degree and it is connected. Can you verify that in polynomial time?

Comment: @btilly I think yes we can go over all the vertices and check if each of them has an even degree and is connected so it will be O(E+V). ? how I can prove that formaly?

Comment: @Martian_mars For advice on how to create formal proofs, see https://docs.google.com/document/d/1_uwl3WDZk_BxNOUL7W0FiPMMxdmi7w4OoP4prUcIs2s/edit?usp=sharing. It sounds harder than it is. Also it should be fair game to cite established theorems such as Euler's theorem. Which makes it easy.

Comment: @btilly if I am in an exam and I saw a question like that I mean L2, how I can be sure I am doing right? because at first glance this language is in NP but the wiki algorithm that shows different I can over maximum O(|E|) to find if I can Euler path or not,  so I run on the first vertex in the graph and check if I can reach to the first vertex I did start and I have each vertex even degree. what means its P

Comment: @Martian_mars You are doing it right if you recognize that this is in NP.  Everything in P is in NP.  After that, recognizing that it is in P requires finding an idea for how to do it in P.  For which you just have to learn the techniques they expect you to know on the test.  In general, it is harder.  As a concrete example, we still do not know whether factoring is in P.

Comment: @btilly Thanks for all, do you think the L2 is in P?
and if yes what is the idea for making it in P?